# Office 365 API SharePoint Taxonomy and Metadata

Tags: office365, office365-apps

I am unable to find Office 365 API documentation about obtaining "taxonomy"/metadata about files. It's possible to create custom columns in SharePoint and store extra information there, but I'm not able to retrieve this via the API.